# lambda capture of std function

Tags: c++, lambda, closures, copy-constructor, std-function

The following code causes **segmentation fault**, but I can't understand why:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
class State {public:int x; int y; State(int _x,int _y):x(_x),y(_y){}};
typedef std::function<bool (const State &s)> FuncT;
std::vector<FuncT> funcs_outside;
class Manager
{
    private: std::vector<FuncT> funcs;
    public:  void insert(const FuncT &g){funcs.push_back(g);}
    // public:  void insert(const FuncT &g){funcs_outside.push_back(g);}
    public:  FuncT getAnd()
    {
        // this should capture everything, no?
        return [=](const State &s)
        {
            bool b=true;
            for (const auto f:funcs)
            // for (const auto f:funcs_outside)
            {
                b = b && f(s);
            }
            return b;
        };
    }
};
FuncT foo(void)
{
    Manager m;
    m.insert([=](const State &s){return s.x<=s.y;});
    m.insert([=](const State &s){return s.x>=s.y;});
    return m.getAnd();
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    auto h = foo();
    std::cout << "h(3,3) = " << h(State(3,3)) << "\n";
    std::cout << "h(3,4) = " << h(State(3,4)) << "\n";
    std::cout << "h(7,2) = " << h(State(7,2)) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

- The `[=]` should capture anything the lambda needs right?
- When I replace `funcs` with `funcs_outside`, **everything works well**.
- What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By `[=]`, pointer `this` is captured also. So you have dangling reference when `getAnd` ends. Strictly, UB occurrs when accessing `funcs` vector.

Comment: @rafix07 how can I fix this?

Comment: You can transfer vector into lambda by init-capture, for example: `[funcs = funcs](const State &s)` (since c++14).

Comment: The tricksy thing is that it doesn't capture `this->funcs`, only `this`, and the access to `funcs` has an implicit `this->`.

Comment: "So you have dangling reference when getAnd ends." The lambda does not capture anything by reference, so there are no dangling references. The lambda does capture `this`, which is a pointer to a `Manager` object. It does not become a dangling pointer when `getAnd` ends, as long as the `Manager` object is still alive. It only becomes a dangling pointer when the `Manager` object goes out of scope at the end of `foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

`getAnd` returns a function object from a member function, which captures and accesses members.

You call that member function on a local variable, and return the resulting function object to the outside of the scope. The members pointed by the function object no longer exist and calling the function object results in undefined behaviour.

> When I replace funcs with funcs_outside, everything works well.

`funcs_outside` is a global object and you access it within its lifetime, so there is no problem.

> how can I fix this?

You could for example capture a copy of the member instead:

```
return [funcs = this->funcs](const State &s)
```